# Ruby get model name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to get the model name of an object. It is simple enough with

`object.model_name`

But how would I go about it when I need to get the inherited model?

`class ModelB < ModelA # I need ModelA`

`object` won't always be a model, it could be an `ActiveRecord::Relation` it could be a `Tire::Collection`, an `Array`

My current implementation is already very messy and is getting bigger:

```
def name(resource)
  model_name = if resource.is_a Array
    name resource.first
  else
    if resource.try(:klass) # ActiveRecord::Relation
      resource.klass.name
    elsif resource.try(:results) # Tire::Collection
      resource.results.first.class.name
    else # ActiveModel
      resource.class.name
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: If you're dealing with STI-type models this will get messy in a hurry.

Comment: Have a look at `resource.ancestors`.

Comment: I think you'd want resource.class.ancestors